# Locking geometry of ArcSDE feature class from ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, enterprise-geodatabase

I am using ArcGIS 10.2.

Does anyone know how I can allow editors to select features and update attributes of an ArcSDE feature class but prevent accidental edits (shifts/deletions) to the geometry?

I have tried making the SHAPE field read-only (via field properties in attribute table) but I was still able to move/delete cells.

I asked here about the "Editable" property for fields, which I had seen in ArcDiagrammer and Enterprise Architect, but you can see Vince's response below.

Comment: Two yrs ago I noticed a field property called "Editable" in ArcGIS Diagrammer, and moved on.

The same "ArcGIS-specific property" can be seen in Sparx Enterprise Architect, using their ArcGIS Workspace Model, at 8:19 here:  [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r9FdJpqDr9I][2]

Of course, this doesn't mean it will work.  Or work on the Shape field. I will test it when I have an hour to spare.

Meanwhile, if anyone has already looked into this I would appreciate any advice or warnings.

  [1]: http://maps.esri.com/Diagrammer/userguide.pdf
  [2]: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r9FdJpqDr9I

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Answer (score 0):

As [commented initially by @Vince](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/177632/locking-geometry-of-arcsde-feature-class-from-arcgis-for-desktop#comment266686_177632):

> I've never heard of this, so I think you're going to need to provide a
>   link to what you read. The only way I'd try to implement this is with
>   a trigger that always fails if the geometry is changed. This would not
>   be a supported behavior for geodatabases.

and in [another comment](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/177632/locking-geometry-of-arcsde-feature-class-from-arcgis-for-desktop/248249#comment266835_177632) responding to [yours](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/177632/locking-geometry-of-arcsde-feature-class-from-arcgis-for-desktop/248249#comment266828_177632):

> That Editable flag isn't a user-configurable property. It's only there
>   because OIDs and rowids aren't editable.